# Problem with bootcamp on SSD: error 0xc00000e9

Tags: macos, bootcamp, ssd, windows

I've recently changed my hard drive for an SSD in my late-2011 mac-book Pro.

I'm trying to partition it and re-install Windows 7 (64 bits) (juste like I had successfully done with my former HDD), using BootCamp Assistant. Everything seems to work fine at first, the partitioning happens, but then when it reboots to install Windows, it always fails:

- I never get the screen where I choose on which partition I wish to install windows
- I get directly to "loading windows files" screen
- After that, I get a black screen saying that I have an error 0xc00000e9, and that I should make sure that all the external devices are properly plugged. It does that regardless of wether I leave the USB key with the Bootcamp drivers plugged in, or not.

Anybody has any idea about how to do that ?

I've read that it could be an AHCI problem with my SSD, but it looks like I need to already be on Windows to fix this, I don't see other options...

My setup:

- Windows 7 Pro 64 bits (iso file burnt on a dvd)
- Macbook Pro late 2011, 15 inch, core i7
- OS X El Capitan (version 10.11.6)
- SSD: Samsung 850EVO 1TB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where the error came from (in particular not from AHCI usage as some people told me), but I got rid of it by switching to a more recent version of Windows 7.